# How to add navigation property item without load navigations in EF code first?

Tags: c#, .net, ef-code-first

I am able to add comment to user like in below. But I have some suspection that when i access Posts navigations so all navigations are loaded if so how i can add comment to user without load it ?

```
public void Add(int userId,string comment)
{
   var user = dbcontext.Users.Find(userId);
   user.Posts.Add(new Comment{Commentbody=comment});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always connect it from the other side...

```
dbcontext.Comments.Add(new Comment{Commentbody=comment, User=user});
```

Comment: Alright but How would you do this when you have many to many relationship between objects ?

Comment: @Freshblood: I don't think it's possible with EF. NHibernate allows it out of the box if you use a bag.

Comment: I think i have to create model which is between many to many objects relation then i will be able to do this.For example i have to create model named CategoryTag for Category and tag relationships then i can set category and tag in CategoryTag model.